# keep div "inside" an image

Tags: html, css, position

I am developing a kind of photo album in "full" screen.
I want to display arrows over an image to be able to go to previous/next one.

Here is my attempt:

https://jsfiddle.net/q49wzey6/

html code:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="left">
    <a href="http://laurent.delrocq.free.fr/test/left.png" style="outline:0">
      <img src="http://laurent.delrocq.free.fr/test/left.png" alt="#">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <a href="http://laurent.delrocq.free.fr/test/right.png">
      <img src="http://laurent.delrocq.free.fr/test/right.png" alt="#">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

a{
  outline:0;
}

.main{
    min-height: 100%;
    background-image:    url(http://laurent.delrocq.free.fr/test/img-1.jpg);
    background-size:     contain; 
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;  
    }

.left{
    position:absolute;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
}

.left a, .right a{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

The problem is that if the browser window is too large, the arrows move outside of the image

How can I make sure that the arrow stays inside the image and that the image still behaves like `background-size: contain;` ?

Comment: You are required to post your minimal example of the problem markup here, not a jsfiddle that can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have added the code in the question. How can I remove the [on hold] status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a parent div with auto height and auto width so it adapts to image size. It also has `display: inline-block` otherwise it would have 100% width.

I positioned the parent relatively so inside it I could put a child div positioned absolute that picks the height and the width from the parent. The rest is easy.

```css
.auto {
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
 }

 .absolute {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  z-index:2;
 }

 .left {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:15px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
 }

 .right {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  right:15px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
 }
```

```html
<div class="auto">
<img src="http://laurent.delrocq.free.fr/test/img-1.jpg" />
<div class="absolute">
 <img src="http://laurent.delrocq.free.fr/test/left.png" alt="#" class="left">
 <img src="http://laurent.delrocq.free.fr/test/right.png" alt="#" class="right">
</div>
</div>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: No Problem! I hope it works fine now with your website

Comment: Now the arrows stay inside the image, but the image does not resize according to the browser window (you can compare with the 2 jsfiddle  links)

Comment: just add the attribute `width:100%` to the image and it will resize according to the browser window.

Comment: With `width:100%`, the image is resized only when you change the window width. But if you make the window vertically smaller than the image height, the image is not resized to fit the window size. A scrollbar is added instead.

Comment: If you want the image to reduce with height you can always use a max width attribute on the image like this:
    width: auto;
    max-height: 100vh;
    height: 100%;

Comment: Thanks a lot!I didn't know the `vh` units. Here is the jsfiddle with the final solution: https://jsfiddle.net/73nbz8b5/1/

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

add

```
position: relative;
background-size: cover;
```

in .main

and if you dont want the image to cover full page - specify width also 
`width: 70%;`

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uhuq3Lxj/)

Comment: background behavior will change. not what questioner asked (last line)